# w1-gpio issue with Waveshare 5" LCD touchscreen and Pi 2

Tags: gpio, pi-2, touchscreen, 1-wire

I've got huge trouble solving the following problem:

I attached a Waveshare 5" LCD touchscreen to a Pi 2 Model B (components and setup listed below), prepared a new SDcard with Raspbian Jessie (not NOOBS), did the normal raspbian-update stuff, installed the waveshare-drivers for jessie (from [here](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD)).
The display works fine - except the touch-functionallity. It shows a crystal-clear picture, but I cannot use the touch control  :| 
Due to the evtest tool, I figured out that there is no input-information at all reaching the Pi.

So I searched the internet and did a lot of stuff. Finally, I encountered a problem that I couldn't get rid off, which makes me assume that this must be the cause for the touch-problem: ***the w1-gpio onewire-connection does not work***.

The detailed problem looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep w1
[    3.463684] hid-generic 0003:046A:B090.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v 1.11 Device [Cherry USB keyboard] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input1
[    5.364888] w1-gpio onewire@0: gpio pin 4, external pullup pin 1, parasitic power 0
[    5.364975] w1_add_master_device: set_pullup requires write_byte or touch_bi , disabling
[    7.444177] w1_master_driver w1_bus_master1: w1_search: max_slave_count 64 reached, will continue next search.
[   54.916570] w1_master_driver w1_bus_master1: Family 0 for 00.800000000000.8c is not registered.
```

As can be seen,

1. the touchscreen does not get listed at all (should be listed as
   input2)
2. w1_add_master_device gets an error
3. the slave count is >64???

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no clue how to solve this. I read / tried some stuff like

- disabling the device_tree
- changed the gpio_pin in the config.txt (just to some values - so here
  might be some potential left)
- lowered the cpu-frequency and activated a cpu-governor (doesn't make
  sense to me, but I read that that might help.. and I was / am
  desperate  :D)
- changed back to an earlier kernel frame -> Pi freezes at startup

Well, has anybody any idea how this problem could be solved (if we assume, that the gpio pins are not broken :D)?
Is there maybe a chance, that the gpio_pin or the external pullup_pin has to be another one? I attached a screenshot how the display should be wired according to waveshare and how the gpio readall of my Pi looks like.

Any idea is very, very very appreciated :)

Some **additional information** that might help:

SPI:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep spi
[    5.754398] spi spi0.1: setting up native-CS1 as GPIO 7
[    5.922907] ads7846 spi0.1: touchscreen, irq 505
[    5.926013] input: ADS7846 Touchscreen as /devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi spi_master/spi0/spi0.1/input/input2
```

**config.txt** (the driver set this up, already tried to lower the xohms)
disable_overscan=1

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0

arm_freq=700

start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
core_freq=250
sdram_freq=400
over_voltage=0
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on

dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4,extpullup=1
```

**Components:**

- Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
- Waveshare 5" LCD touchscreen (no USB, connected via HDMI and GPIOs)
  (http://www.waveshare.com/5inch-hdmi-lcd.htm)
- SanDisk Ultra 32 GB micro SDcard
- 5V / 2.4 A stable power source (not plugged into my pc)

**Setup**

- Raspbian Jessie (latest version / updates) (**not** NOOBS!)
- Linux raspberrypi 4.1.20-v7+ #862 SMP Sat Mar 19 20:37:37 GMT 2016
  armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I don't see why you are blaming 1-wire.  Does the touch panel work if you remove or comment out dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4,extpullup=1 and reboot?

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the line does not change anything regarding the touch-functionality. I blame 1-wire, because the 1-wire connection tells the pi that a touch event is taking place and, additionally, it is the only software-component I could find out that is realted to the touchscreen and gives an error

Comment: Why do you think the screen is using 1-wire?  It seems to be using SPI which is normally a 4-wire system.

Comment: Because the display-driver itself creates the w1-overlay - there is no reason for the driver to create it when it doesn't use it.

Comment: Just because there is no reason hasn't stopped them from doing it.  **The w1-gpio line has nothing to do with your waveshare screen.  It has been put there by mistake.**  The ads7846 line is for the touchscreen.  It is the touchscreen controller.  Look in /boot/overlays/README.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else is having the same problem - my solution to fix this was.. to get a new dispaly :D Unluckily, the former one was broken.

Despite this, in order to help others dealing with problems regarding this display, please have a look at **romneys** configuration on this site: 
[Click me](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=141529&p=936984#p936984)

The setup he posted there works with my new display, wherefore it might help others to find a solution regarding configuration problems. Thanks again to romney :)